# JAVAFX WeView does not support SVG Filters?

Tags: javascript, javafx, webview, webkit, css-transitions

I am applying a css transition triggered by javascript style change to an svg g element. The transition works perfectly on my browser Chrome, and the transitions are applied to both property changes. However in my JAVAFX web view the transition properties interfere with eachother.

CSS

```
    #viewBox[data-focus-state=off] g{
        opacity:0; 
    }
    #viewBox[data-focus-state=on] g{ 
        opacity:1; 
    }

    #viewBox g{

        -webkit-transition: .7s;

    }
```

HTML

```
<svg id="viewBox" viewBox="0 0 352 182" preserveAspectRatio="none" data-focus-state="off">

                <g   style="-webkit-transform: translate(310px, 45px);">
                    <circle r="10" cy="0" cx="0" style="fill: rgb(151, 215, 241);" ></circle>
                    <text transform="translate(-170, 0)">Testing</text>
                </g>
</svg>
```

In the javascript i simply toggle the data-focus-state attribute to trigger an opacity change and at the same time also set the style attribute to a new transform translate with new coordinates.

Does anyone know if this is an issue specific to the JAVAFX webview? I tried researching it's version of webkit but I couldn't find anything that would indicate there is no support for concurrent css transitions on the same element.

**UPDATE***

It turns out that simultaneous CSS animations are now supported, however applying filters to svg elements still causes things to break.

Comment: What JDK version are you on? If I remember correctly I once investigated something along the lines if the webview supports SVG and came to the conclusion, that the support is only partial.

Comment: I'm on jdk 1.8, after further research it looks like there is a proposal to upgrade to the latest version of webkit, perhaps this is the problem?

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/239

Comment: This might alleviate some issued, but probably not all of them. Are you on the latest update version (1.8.0_72)? There were some bugs in version 45 through 60 that caused me some troubles, that were partially resolved with 66.

Comment: I'm on 1.8.0_66 I'll update and try again, whilst taking a look at their change log :) Thanks for the tip will update as soon as I have some findings

Comment: @hotzst unfortunately the latest update to 1.8 didn't solve the animation issues :/ I would like to stick to using css transitions for this since it's a very simple animation , but I'm sure if I switch to requestAnimationFrame, the JavaFX Web view will support that just fine.